# typescript react HOC that only adds ref to ComponentClass

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following HOC:

```
function isComponentClass(Component: React.ComponentClass) {
  return Component.prototype.render;
}

export const withShortcuts = function<T>(createShortcuts: CreateShortcuts) {
  return (Component: React.ComponentClass<T> | React.StatelessComponent<T>) => {
    class WrappedShortcuts extends React.Component<T> {
      ref: React.RefObject<T>;
      constructor(props: T) {
        super(props);

        this.ref = React.createRef();
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Shortcuts createShortcuts={createShortcuts}>
            {isComponentClass(Component) ? <Component ref={this.ref} {...this.props} /> : <Component {...this.props} />}
          </Shortcuts>
        );
      }
    }

    return hoistStatics(WrappedShortcuts, Component);
  };
};
```

The problem is `isComponentClass` is not letting the TS compiler know that I can add a `ref` to a class when it is true and I get the error:

> Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & {
>   children?: ReactNode; }'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `isComponentClass` to be a type-guard. A type-guard function is a function that changes the type of the parameter passed to it when used in an if or `?:`. See more about type guards [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html):

```
function isComponentClass<T>(Component: React.ComponentClass<T> | React.StatelessComponent<T>) : Component is React.ComponentClass<T> {
    return Component.prototype.render;
}

isComponentClass(Component) ? 
   <Component ref={this.ref} {...this.props} /> :  // Component is React.ComponentClass<T> here 
   <Component {...this.props} /> // Component is React.StatelessComponent<T> here
```

Comment: that sounds good but the stateless component is now of type `never` after callin `isComponentClass` and complains with JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Comment: @dagda1 what version were you using, just out of curiosity, type guards are pretty old in the language.

Comment: I was using 2.6.2